# Juniper Netscreen Log Files

Tags: firewall, router, scp

I am trying to find a way to copy the log files from a Juniper SSG5 so that I can programmatically analyse them.

I know that it is possible to scp files from the Juniper but I have been unable to find where the logs are saved on the device.

Any help on locating these logs (all of them) would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no simple way to access the log files on the Juniper Netscreen however it does provide options for configuring remote logging using syslog.

This can be configured to point to a syslog server on the network which can in turn be configured to log these remote messages to a local file (or pass them on to another syslog server)

Answer (score 0):

show log command will give you filenames.
show log

user@host> show log
total 57518
-rw-r--r--  1 root  bin      211663 Oct  1 19:44 dcd
-rw-r--r--  1 root  bin      999947 Oct  1 19:41 dcd.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root  bin      999994 Oct  1 17:48 dcd.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root  bin      238815 Oct  1 19:44 rpd